# Rolling standard deviation offset by 1 row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns for player names and points scored, where each row is one game. I would like to make a new column "STDev L2" which takes a rolling standard deviation based on the last two games. I would like the previous 2 games, not including the current game, to be used. Is there an elegant way to offset by one row?

Here's what I would expect:

```
Player | Points | STDev L2
Bob    | 23.9   |  0
Bob    | 27.9   |  0
Bob    | 18.5   |  2.828427
```

My current code and output:

```
df['STDev L2'] = df.groupby('Player')['Points'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(2).std())

Player | Points | STDev L2
Bob    | 23.9   |  
Bob    | 27.9   |  2.828427
Bob    | 18.5   |  6.646804
```

Also, is there a way to make the first blank row be 0 instead of blank?

EDIT: this worked for me! thanks @ChrisA

```
df['STDev L2'] = df.groupby('Player')['Points'].apply(lambda x : x.shift(1).rolling(2).std().fillna(0))
```

Comment: You current approach seems like the way to go. You could just use `fillna` for the blank values

Comment: add `shift`..? ie `....apply(lambda x : x.shift().rolling(2).std().fillna(0))`

Comment: @ChrisA that worked perfect! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the pandas dataframe [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method.

You can use that to get a shifted rolling std dev and than add that shifted data back to your original dataframe.

Regarding your second question, one approach would be to simply use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on the result. It looks like you might be able to use the `limit` parameter to have it only fill the beginning (untested, but that's my interpretation of the docs).